# How to Keep Data Paired Together in Insertion Sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

I've been working with data from a file and keeping them paired together. I need to sort the data alphabetically while keeping them paired together at the same time. I have successfully done it with bubble sort here:

```
     for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < count - 1; j++)
         {
             if (email [j].compareToIgnoreCase (email [j + 1]) > 0)
             {
                 temp1 = email [j];
                 email [j] = email [j + 1];
                 email [j + 1] = temp1;

                 temp2 = fname [j];
                 fname [j] = fname [j + 1];
                 fname [j + 1] = temp2;

                 temp3 = lname [j];
                 lname [j] = lname [j + 1];
                 lname [j + 1] = temp3;

                 temp4 = city [j];
                 city [j] = city [j + 1];
                 city [j + 1] = temp4;

                 temp5 = age [j];
                 age [j] = age [j + 1];
                 age [j + 1] = temp5;
             }
         }
     }
}
```

I get an output like this:
Email:
bobbarley@gmail.com
First Name:
Bob
Last Name:
Barley
City:
Vancouver
Age:
13
Email:
felixfixed@gmail.com
First Name:
Felix
Last Name:
Fixed
City:
Boston
Age:
24
Email:
joejake@gmail.com
First Name:
Joe
Last Name:
Jake
City:
Toronto
Age:
32

On the other hand I have an insertion sort, but I can't keep the data together. Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
    {
        String current = fname [i];
        int j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && current.compareToIgnoreCase (fname [j]) < 0)
        {
            fname [j + 1] = fname [j];
            j--;
        }
        fname [j + 1] = current;
    }
```

With this part, I get this output:

First Name:
Bob
Last Name:
Jake
City:
Toronto
Age:
32
Email:
joejake@gmail.com
First Name:
Felix
Last Name:
Barley
City:
Vancouver
Age:
13
Email:
bobbarley@gmail.com
First Name:
Joe
Last Name:
Fixed
City:
Boston
Age:
24
Email:
felixfixed@gmail.com

Comment: Java is an **Object-Oriented Language**. *Use it!!* Don't use parallel arrays. Create a class, e.g. named `Person` with 5 fields, then use a single array of those objects.

Answer (score 0):

You perform the ordering by bubbles comparing by mail and then your other fields, but the insert only compares the name why? perhaps you should not compare in the insert with the others so that it will be ordered

```
{for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
    String current = fname [i];
    int j = i - 1;

    while ((j >= 0 && current.compareToIgnoreCase (fname [j]) < 0) and j>=0 && current.compareToIgnoreCase (email[j]....)
    {
        fname [j + 1] = fname [j];
        j--;
    }
    fname [j + 1] = current;
}
```